# Unable to login mysql by mysql-workbench when username contains '%'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, navicat

Just like title,I can login by mysql-navicat.
But when I used mysql-workbench, it says Access Denied

[image]

I guess this may be caused by a username...

Have you encountered a similar problem?

Comment: please share the logs in text, and the errors you get. furthermore describe the issue in detailed steps. also - do you have another user that works? can you log in through mysql-cli?

Comment: It is not a good idea to have wildcard characters in usernames

Comment: @JoSSte
Yes, I can log in through mysql-cli and navicat.

Comment: @DaveStokes I think so too.But I don't have permission to create new users or change this. =.=

Comment: @JoSSte Well..This workbench is :MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Linux/Unix version 8.0.13 CE build 13780177 (64 bit).

The mysql server version is : 5.5.0.0 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 0):

Well..
Server version: 5.5.0.0 MySQL Community Server (GPL).

The version of the workbench I used before was MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Linux/Unix version 8.0.13 CE build 13780177 (64 bit).

Now I install the MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Linux/Unix version 6.3.10 CE build 12092614 (64 bit).

It can work.
Maybe the 8.0 workbench replaced the wildcard in the username..

Comment: If this is just comments to your original question n, edit the question. Answer posts should contain... Answers

Comment: @JoSSte It's the answer...I fix this problem by installing the low version of the workbench.Thanks for your help.